# division in while loop

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, division

I want to use a `while` loop to divide `n` numbers and print the quotient. For example if the user entered n=3, the program will ask for 3 numbers. Say the user entered 2, 2, and 3. The program then performs the following operation: 2/2/3 and then prints the answer ( i.e. 0.3333). I have a  program that uses a `while` loop for addition, division, and multiplication perfectly, but in division, it divides 1 by all the numbers entered(1/2/2/3). How do I fix it? Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(void)
{
int n, k=0;
float total=1, number;
printf("\nEnter the number of elements you want to divide:");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Please enter %d numbers one by one: \n",n);
while(k<n)
{ 
    scanf("%f",&number);
    total=number/number;
    k=k+1;
}
printf("Quotient of %d numbers = %f \n",n,total);
_getch();
}
```

Comment: this line: float total=1, should be float total=1.0f;  first because 1 is not a float number and 1.0 would default to double.

Comment: when using scanf() always check the return code (should be 1 in this case) to assure that the parameters were actually read.  The calls to scanf() after the first, should have a ' ' as the first character of the format parameter so that white space, (like the '\n') are skipped over.

Comment: this line: total=number/number;  the code is dividing a number by itself, so naturally, the result will always be 1.  Per your comments, you want to divide each number by the prior number.  Your code needs another variable 'oldNumber' (what to initialize this number to?) then perform total += oldNumber/number;  without the '+=', the value of total is not the sum of the divide operations but only the result of the latest divide.  Initializing total to 1 will result in the wrong resulting value,  it should be total = 1.0f;

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
total=number/number;
```

to

```
if (k==0) 
    total = number;
else 
    total=total/number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with `k=1` then right before the while loop put

```
scanf('%f', &total);
```

You might want to wrap that line in `if (n!=0)`. This way there's no `if` statement in the loop for very marginal, minuscule performance gains!

Then just change

```
total=number/number;
```

to

```
total=total/number;
```

and you should be set to go.